# Where is the taghelper for asp-area or how to create a hyperlink with an area?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have read about:

asp-action or asp-controller taghelper. But what about asp-area ?

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
```

How would you extend the above hyperlink with an area parameter?

This did not work:

```
<a asp-controller="Application/Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
```

Looking at the mvc 6.0 beta8 source code there is no asp-area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asp-route-*` to pass route params. That *should* work for passing an area as well, since that's essentially how you do with `Url.Action`. So try:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About" asp-route-area="MyArea">About</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the relevant source code, you can find it in the [`AnchorTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs).

As @chris-pratt mentionned, `asp-route-area` will work since area is basically a route parameter as defined per the template `{area}/{controller}/{action}`.

`asp-route-` will map every route data into a dictionary called `routeValues` and invoke the `IHtmlGenerator` in such a way:

```
tagBuilder = Generator.GenerateActionLink(
                    linkText: string.Empty,
                    actionName: Action,
                    controllerName: Controller,
                    protocol: Protocol,
                    hostname: Host,
                    fragment: Fragment,
                    routeValues: routeValues,
                    htmlAttributes: null);
```

For other uses of this TagHelper, do not hesite to look at the source as TagHelpers are pretty self-contained and easy to undertand. You can also see all other TagHelpers that are being defined [right here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers).